# Asp.NET return ActionResult while adding data to user session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, actionresult

I have a method similar to this one:

```
 public ActionResult Index() 
 {    
    Session["test"] = GetData();
    return View(); 
 }
```

Because my `GetData()` method takes too long, I was wondering if i can do something *async* in order to return the `View` while `GetData()` is running and adding the object to user session.
I already thought at splitting this method into 2 methods the first to return 'View()' and the second one to be called with ajax and just for adding object to session, but i want to use this as a last resort.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can's you use AJAX to load dat asynchronously on the client side? Why is it your last resort?

Comment: Using an async method for long-running tasks will free up a thread on the server, but it won't improve responsiveness to the user. I agree that AJAX seems the way to go - but of course it depends if there any implications of not immediately adding this object to the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because my GetData() method takes too long, I was wondering if i can
>   do something async in order to return the View while GetData() is
>   running and adding the object to user session.

You definitely do not want to run long running query on *initial page load*. User might think the network connection was lost, and keeps pressing F5 to refresh the page.

Instead, you want two action methods -

1. 1st Action Method returns regular view. Then at client-side, you make Ajax  request to Action Method 2.
2. 2nd Action Method returns JSON response

***FYI:*** You want to make sure 2nd Action Method requires user login to access. Otherwise, you might encounter DDoS attack.